# не ставится mssql-server 2017 на linux mint 18.3 x64

Tags: linux, sql-server, зависимости

```
esin@lenovoVerm ~ $ sudo apt install mssql-server
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 mssql-server : Зависит: openssl (<= 1.1.0) но 1.1.0g-2.1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

выполнил все нижеописанные советы, не помогло.

Совет 1
Введите и выполните в терминале, эту команду, чтобы исправить битые пакеты:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

Совет 2
Если приведенная выше команда не помогла, попробуйте выполнить следующие:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

Совет 3
Вы также можете попробовать следующие команды:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Совет 4
И ещё:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

Совет 5
Также как вариант, если проблема с битыми пакетами не решилась способами выше:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install имя_софта
```

Совет 6
Попробуйте:
    sudo apt dist-upgrade

Comment: Попробуйте `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

прошу прощения, все оказалось просто, нужно было откатить openssl до совместимой версии.
сделал через *aptitude*. сначала протупил, поэтому не вышло

всем спасибо за просмотры

Comment: Стоит команду целиком в ответе привести. Или номер версии.